# Does Qt Visual Studio Add-in support Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition?

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2013, qt-vs-addin, vs-community-edition

As the title asks, does Qt Visual Studio Add-in support Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition or not? That is, can it be installed and integrated into VS2013 Community Edition?

Asking because it doesn't support VS Express, and the Community Edition might lack some features needed by the Add-in, as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unlike VS Express,  Visual Studio Community Edition supports both plugins and cross-platform development, and also it's free. So Qt VS Add-in would work on VS Community since the latest version of the Add-in supports VS 2013. There would be no problem and it should work normal, unless you encounter a bug in Add-in.